# Detectar onBackPressed() desde la actividad principal

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity

Tengo una aplicación con un botón que nos lleva de la Actividad A (Main) a la Actividad B, me gustaría que cuando cierro la actividad B con un onBackPressed() la aplicación A (Main) detectara que vuelve a ser la actividad activa y actuara realizando un método, ¿es eso posible?

Gracias de antemano,

Edit1:

Código en MainActivity()

```
        botonActividadB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActividadB.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(a);
        }
    });
```

Código en ActividadB

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}
```

Mi intención es que onBackPressed haga que MainActivity ejecute un método, sin necesidad de pasar parámetros entre MainActivity y ActividadB, entonces, como hago para que MainActivity detecte que ActividadB ha terminado?

Comment: He añadido el código que quiero tratar, simplemente un Intent que llama a un Acitvity y un finish en la actividad que llama.

Comment: Macia, busca startActivityForResult, es lo que necesitas. Si tienes algún problema a la hora de utilizarlo puedes editar tu pregunta y decir lo que te pasa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar usando `startActivityForResult()`, en tu MainActivity define una variable con un valor que determine regresas desde la Activity B:

```
  private static final int VALOR = 12;
```

Agrega el método `onActivityResult()`, que sera el que recibira la información.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i("MainActivity", "onActivityResult() requestCode : " +requestCode);
    if (requestCode == VALOR){

        switch (resultCode) {
            case RESULT_OK:
                Log.i("MainActivity", "onActivityResult() RESULT_OK");
                break;

            case RESULT_CANCELED:
                Log.i("MainActivity", "onActivityResult() RESULT_CANCELED");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

y realiza de esta forma el Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity3.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, CHILD_REQUEST);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

de esta forma al terminar Activity B mediante el método

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}
```

obtendrás el resultado en MainActivity dentro del método `onActivityResult()`, revisa este excelente tutorial en español:

https://www.limecreativelabs.com/startactivityforresult-actividades-que-devuelven-resultados/